# Messages not appearing when calling Discord bot command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, yfinance

I wrote this script for a Discord bot to display stock information when calling the `!stock` command. I'm using the discord.api and yfinance libraries for Python. Bot is online when running the script I've written, with the output looking something like this:

```
2023-02-24 15:40:17 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-02-24 15:40:18 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: <id_number>).
```

The permissions that are active are `Send Messages`, `Read Message History` and `Add Reactions`, as well as I have all the Privileged Gateway Intents active, so I don't think it's an issue in regards to permissions.

I've provided the script below:

```py
import os
import discord
import yfinance as yf
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# token .env information
load_dotenv()
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

# initialize the necessary intents for the bot
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # check if the message is from the bot itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # check if the message starts with "!stock"
    if message.content.startswith("!stock"):
        stock_info = message.content.split(" ")[1]
        try:
            # get stock information
            stock = yf.Ticker(stock_info)
            stock_info = stock.info
            await message.channel.send(f'{stock_info["longName"]} ({stock_info["symbol"]})')
            await message.channel.send(f'Current Price: ${stock_info["regularMarketPrice"]}')
            await message.channel.send(f'Day\'s Change: ${stock_info["regularMarketChange"]} ({stock_info["regularMarketChangePercent"]}%)')
        except ValueError:
            await message.channel.send("Invalid Ticker or Company Name")

client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As per the recommendation of @Paul, I've added this to my script: `intents.message_content = True`. However, now I'm getting this peculiar error. From what I can see it could be due to outdated libraries, but I've upgraded both discord.py and yfinance and the error pertains:

```
2023-02-24 16:18:56 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ioanb\Development Personal\Bill the Stock Bot\main.py", line 29, in on_message    
    stock_info = stock.info
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\ticker.py", line 138, in info
    return self.get_info()
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 1475, in get_info
    data = self._quote.info
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\scrapers\quote.py", line 95, in info
    self._scrape(self.proxy)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\scrapers\quote.py", line 124, in _scrape
    json_data = self._data.get_json_data_stores(proxy=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 41, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 311, in get_json_data_stores
    stores = decrypt_cryptojs_aes_stores(data, keys)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 162, in decrypt_cryptojs_aes_stores
    raise Exception("yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response")
Exception: yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response
quote.py", line 124, in _scrape    json_data = self._data.get_json_data_stores(proxy=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 41, in wrapped    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 311, in get_json_data_stores
    stores = decrypt_cryptojs_aes_stores(data, keys)  File "C:\Users\ioanb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\yfinance\data.py", line 162, in decrypt_cryptojs_aes_stores
    raise Exception("yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response")
Exception: yfinance failed to decrypt Yahoo data response
```

Comment: You are missing the [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intent#discord.Intents.message_content) Intent, consider adding `intents.message_content = True`.

Comment: Hey @Paul, I added the comment you suggested, however now I'm getting another error, left it in the update section of the question

Comment: It seems to be a *recent* know issue on the `yfinance` library, more about [the issue here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1407).
I suggest you to find another library, which uses APIs and avoid scraping.